# При наведении на список подсвечивать нужную область

Tags: jquery, события, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Суть проблемы:
у меня есть интерактивная карта России и список городов, работает все следующим образом - при наведении на область появляется подсказка с названием и номером. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на список также подсвечивалась нужная область.

```
    var tooltip = {
    options: {
        attr_name: "tooltip",
        blank_text: "()",
        newline_entity: "  ",
        max_width: 0, 
        delay: 200, 
        skip_tags: ["link", "style"] 
    },

    t: document.createElement("DIV"),
    c: null,
    g: false,
    canvas: null,

    m: function(e){
        if (tooltip.g){
            var x = window.event ? event.clientX + (tooltip.canvas.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) : e.pageX;
            var y = window.event ? event.clientY + (tooltip.canvas.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) : e.pageY;
            tooltip.a(x-24, y-114);
        }
    },

    d: function(){
        tooltip.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName(document.compatMode && document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat" ? "HTML" : "BODY")[0];
        tooltip.t.setAttribute("id", "tooltip");
        document.body.appendChild(tooltip.t);
        if (tooltip.options.max_width) tooltip.t.style.maxWidth = tooltip.options.max_width + "px"; // all but ie
        var a = document.all && !window.opera ? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName("*"); // in opera 9 document.all produces type mismatch error
        var l = a.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){

            if (!a[i] || tooltip.options.skip_tags.in_array(a[i].tagName.toLowerCase())) continue;

            var tooltip_title = a[i].getAttribute("title"); // returns form object if IE & name="title"; then IE crashes; so...
            if (tooltip_title && typeof tooltip_title != "string") tooltip_title = "";

            var tooltip_alt = a[i].getAttribute("alt");
            var tooltip_blank = a[i].getAttribute("target") && a[i].getAttribute("target") == "_blank" && tooltip.options.blank_text;
            if (tooltip_title || tooltip_blank){
                a[i].setAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name, tooltip_blank ? (tooltip_title ? tooltip_title  + " " + tooltip.options.blank_text : tooltip.options.blank_text) : tooltip_title);
                if (a[i].getAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name)){
                    a[i].removeAttribute("title");
                    if (tooltip_alt && a[i].complete) a[i].removeAttribute("alt");
                    tooltip.l(a[i], "mouseover", tooltip.s);
                    tooltip.l(a[i], "mouseout", tooltip.h);
                }
            }else if (tooltip_alt && a[i].complete){
                a[i].setAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name, tooltip_alt);
                if (a[i].getAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name)){
                    a[i].removeAttribute("alt");
                    tooltip.l(a[i], "mouseover", tooltip.s);
                    tooltip.l(a[i], "mouseout", tooltip.h);
                }
            }
            if (!a[i].getAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name) && tooltip_blank){
                //
            }
        }
        document.onmousemove = tooltip.m;
        window.onscroll = tooltip.h;
        tooltip.a(-99, -99);
    },

    _: function(s){
        s = s.replace(/\&/g,"&amp;");
        s = s.replace(/\</g,"&lt;");
        s = s.replace(/\>/g,"&gt;");
        return s;
    },

    s: function(e){
        if (typeof tooltip == "undefined") return;
        var d = window.event ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;
        if (!d.getAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name)) return;
        var s = d.getAttribute(tooltip.options.attr_name);
        if (tooltip.options.newline_entity){
            var s = tooltip._(s);

            var lines = s.split('--');
            var res_text = '';
            for ( var k = 0; k<lines.length; k++) {
                res_text += '<div class="tooltip_line">'+ lines[k] +'</div>';
            }
            //s = s.replace(eval("/" + tooltip._(tooltip.options.newline_entity) + "/g"), "<br />");
            tooltip.t.innerHTML = res_text;
        }else{
            if (tooltip.t.firstChild) tooltip.t.removeChild(tooltip.t.firstChild);
            tooltip.t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
        }
        tooltip.c = setTimeout(function(){
            tooltip.t.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }, tooltip.options.delay);
        tooltip.g = true;
    },

    h: function(e){
        if (typeof tooltip == "undefined") return;
        tooltip.t.style.visibility = "hidden";
        if (!tooltip.options.newline_entity && tooltip.t.firstChild) tooltip.t.removeChild(tooltip.t.firstChild);
        clearTimeout(tooltip.c);
        tooltip.g = false;
        tooltip.a(-99, -99);
    },

    l: function(o, e, a){
        if (o.addEventListener) o.addEventListener(e, a, false); // was true--Opera 7b workaround!
        else if (o.attachEvent) o.attachEvent("on" + e, a);
            else return null;
    },

    a: function(x, y){
        var w_width = tooltip.canvas.clientWidth ? tooltip.canvas.clientWidth + (tooltip.canvas.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) : window.innerWidth + window.pageXOffset;
        var w_height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset : tooltip.canvas.clientHeight + (tooltip.canvas.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop); // should be vice verca since Opera 7 is crazy!

        if (document.all && document.all.item && !window.opera) tooltip.t.style.width = tooltip.options.max_width && tooltip.t.offsetWidth > tooltip.options.max_width ? tooltip.options.max_width + "px" : "auto";

        var t_width = tooltip.t.offsetWidth;
        var t_height = tooltip.t.offsetHeight;

        tooltip.t.style.left = x + 8 + "px";
        tooltip.t.style.top = y + 8 + "px";

        if (x + t_width > w_width) tooltip.t.style.left = w_width - t_width + "px";
        if (y + t_height > w_height) tooltip.t.style.top = w_height - t_height + "px";
    }
}

Array.prototype.in_array = function(value){
    var l = this.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
        if (this[i] === value) return true;
    return false;
};

var root = window.addEventListener || window.attachEvent ? window : document.addEventListener ? document : null;
if (root){
    if (root.addEventListener) root.addEventListener("load", tooltip.d, false);
    else if (root.attachEvent) root.attachEvent("onload", tooltip.d);
}
```

Связь между областью и элементом списка осуществляю по полю "data-number"
Xочу сделать перехват события следующим кодом:

```
$('.city_list').on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
var num_li = $(this).attr('data-number');

$('.map11 area').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('data-number') != undefined && $(this).attr('data-number') == num_li) {
        $(this).triggerHandler('mouseover');
    }
})
```

}).on('mouseout', 'li', function() {
        var num_li = $(this).attr('data-number');

```
    $('.map11 area').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-number') != undefined && $(this).attr('data-number') == num_li) {
            $(this).triggerHandler("mouseout");
        }
    })
})
```

Но ничего не выходит. Помогите, я просто начинающий js программист и вероятно что-то не понимаю в вызовt событий.

Comment: у вас все запутанно, выделите проблему, в тесте все работает:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tHF7U/

Comment: http://architectvan.com/polygon/ вот пример 
при наведении на пункт списка подсвечивается область на карте, но не получается запустить скрипт который показивает tooltip.

Comment: это нормально что оренбург у вас в ледовитом океане ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.in_array` **никогда** так не делайте. к тому-же существует indexOf ну и дикая смесь кода без jQuery и с jQuery тоже нехорошо, особенно в свете навешиваения событий через onmouseover=

Comment: Ето не мой код, помогите мне перехватить собитие которое я описал выше. Очень нужно, уже 4 дня парюсь.

Comment: нет, у вас денег не хватит.

----

tooltip.d() только это вам не нужно, оно устанавливает обработчики событий, и многожды это делать не нужно. вам наверное нужно запустить tooltip.m(e) с вручную созданным (e) чтобы координаты мыши подделать.

но вообще, вам этот наверное не подходит, поищите jQuery  плагин. подходящий, или лучше воспользуйтесь d3 или openlayer

Comment: я понял) тогда подскажите как запустить "d: function(){ .." при onmouseover